# wget + JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, browser, wget

I have this webpage that uses client-side JavaScript to format data on the page before it's displayed to the user.

Is it possible to somehow use `wget` to download the page and use some sort of client-side JavaScript engine to format the data as it would be displayed in a browser?

Comment: Are the pages on the same server?

Comment: wget would run on your server, which means it's not client-side...

Comment: No, it's just some random webpage on the internet. I would not be running wget on the same server as where the webpage is hosted.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You could probably make that happen with something like [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/)

You can write a phantomjs script that will load the page like a browser would, and then either take screenshots or use JS to inspect the page and pull out data.

Comment: See [command-line-browser-with-js-support](http://superuser.com/questions/448514/command-line-browser-with-js-support) for phantomjs script to use.

Comment: Beware of the dependencies when installing PhantomJS. You may as well be running headless Firefox.

Answer (score 9):

Here is a simple little phantomjs script that triggers javascript on a webpage and allows you to pull it down locally:

`file: get.js`

```
var page = require('webpage').create(),
  system = require('system'), address;

address = system.args[1];
page.scrollPosition= { top: 4000, left: 0}  
page.open(address, function(status) {
  if (status !== 'success') {
    console.log('** Error loading url.');
  } else {
    console.log(page.content);
  }
  phantom.exit();
});
```

Use it as follows: 
`$> phantomjs /path/to/get.js "http://www.google.com" > "google.html"`

Changing `/path/to`, `url` and `filename` to what you want.

Comment: Would you add code to deal with `document.cookie` and `location.href` and then fetch the new `href` ?

Answer (score 2):

Not with wget, as I doubt it includes any form of a JavaScript engine.  However, you could use WebKit to process the page, and thus the output.

Using things like this as a base for how to get the content: http://situated.wordpress.com/2008/06/04/take-screenshots-of-a-website-from-the-command-line/

Answer (score 0):

If you just need the links, you can parse them out of [elinks](https://github.com/rkd77/elinks#readme)' `-dump` feature.

This also gives an ASCII rendition of the document, but it does not give processed HTML as far as I can see.

A filter which works for me is something like:

```
sed -ne 's!^.*[0-9].*\(https://.*\)$!\1!p'
```