# get element infromation from a page that use javascript

Tags: javascript, html, inspector

in a browser such as google chrome , when I want to get information of the page , I just select view page source but in some sites that use javascript you cant do that , so I discovered that on any element such as a button and select inspect element it will show me the information that I need , and its really great but I want to do this automatically 
for example for simple pages that use html , I just use wget to save the page to text to analyze it later , but for pages that use javascript and css its impossibile ,
so my question is there a tool or any way to get the information I need and save it to text
lets say I specify the site and the element (button ) and it will download the code and will save it to text

Comment: now I am thinking about a way , using a batch to make chrome or firefox to save the output of `Ctrl + Shift + J` into text file , is it possible ?

Comment: prepend `view-source:` to the beginning of the URL to see the source code behind a webpage.

Answer (score 1):

If you use chrome, you can do `Ctrl + Shift + J` to get the Developer tools window open. Click the Top left most icon (Elements) to see the DOM as it stands after JavaScript modification.

In IE (7 or above I think) use `F12` to open a similar window.

And in FireFox you can use `Ctrl + Shift +I` to open a similar window.

And for automating this process try using http://www.phantomjs.org/ (*as suggested here: [wget + JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5901661/wget-javascript)*)

**Edit:**

There is a Save button in IE which saves the current DOM:

[image]

In FireFox after you have pushed `Ctrl + Shift + I` press `Ctrl + S` and it will save the current DOM.

**Edit 2:**

Download PhantomJS, create a file called `script.js` paste this into it:

```
system = require('system');
var page = new WebPage();
page.open(system.args[1], function (status) {
    if(status == 'success') {
        html = page.evaluate(function() {
            return document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML;
        }); 
        console.log(html);
    } else {
        console.log('Page could not be loaded');
    }
    phantom.exit();
});
```

Run `phantomjs script.js http://www.website.co.uk > website.html` at the comment line (script.js and phantom.exe will have to be in the current working directory). Change `http://www.website.co.uk` to the website you need to download and `website.html` so the`html file you want to save to.

Comment: Wow, `Ctrl + Shift + J` is the third shortcut I've learned: `Ctrl + Shift + I` works too (like in Opera) and `F12` also works (like in Firefox)

Comment: Haha, I didn't know about those other two.

Comment: @Chief17 thank you `Ctrl + Shift + J` gave me what I want , now the hard thing to find a tool to do the same thing using a batch , I will read the topic that you have posted

Comment: @Chief17 but I want to this automatically using a batch file ,so I wonder If I can do this by commands

Comment: That's what PhantomJS can do. I've posted a working example for you that you can use right away. Check `Edit 2`.

Comment: ok thanks for your help ,but doing this it will download the html code which I can do by wget , but I want to download the a page that use javascript that only inspect element will show that in browser

Comment: This will download the HTML code after javascript has been run on page load, so if there is no page content and it is loaded with ajax, you will get the resulting DOM. If I have misunderstood you, please could you try and rephrase what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: No, its possible though. Maybe try writing a console application in C#.NET and use the web browser component to get the source code of the page.