# Download content of CSV file via curl from secure POST request

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to download a file that is generated when a `POST` button is pressed on an HTTPS page.  I'm having to pass the contents of a cookie to show that I'm logged in but I've tested that elsewhere on the same site and that's all working fine.

I'm successfully generating the `POST` request to request the data that I need and I'm sending it but I'm getting nothing back from the web server at all.

Here's my code:

```
// Build header
$header = array();
$header[0] = "Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,";
$header[0] .= "text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5";
$header[] = "Cache-Control: max-age=0";
$header[] = "Connection: keep-alive";
$header[] = "Keep-Alive: 300";
$header[] = "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7";
$header[] = "Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5";
$header[] = "Pragma: ";
$header[] = "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

// Now do transfer
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://domain/pathtoscript");

// Send referer to make this look real
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $referer);

// And disguise ourselves as a browser
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);

// Return results as a string
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

// Follow redirects
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);

// Now send post data
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);

// Define where we can store cookies
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookieFile);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookieFile);

// Sender header and permitted encodings
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '');

// Actually do it !
$result = curl_exec ($ch);

curl_close ($ch);

// Show result in browser (should be CSV text file)
echo $result;
```

What am I doing wrong ?  I don't want a dialogue box to open to prompt me to save the file, I'd just like the content of the file in `$result` so that I can parse it later in my application.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: you are not returning anything... where's the download code? (header, echo the result...)

Comment: can you show the code where you make the POST request to.

Comment: You may be able to get some help from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22264028/391161) that I wrote a while back.

Comment: All POST parameters are put into the $postData variable - that part works.  What download code would I have to add to get the response into the $result variable ?

Comment: That's a useful example @merlin2011 - thanks.  I've made the changes that I thought I'd need (edited above too) but without success :-(