# Wget on HTML once JavaScript is executed

Tags: javascript, wget

I am trying to get the HTML of a page with `wget`, but the problem is that I'd like to get all the content of the page once the JavaScript is executed.

Is there a way to simulate the browser to get the complete HTML after the JavaScript `document.ready` function?

Comment: You can use ajax to do it.

Comment: but with a bash program is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think wget has the requirements you are looking for. A previous solution:

[wget + JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5901661/wget-javascript)

mentions using phantomjs.