# wget is not returning the correct page

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, automation, wget

I am trying to script a process using wget. I have a list of websites I need to check if they are mobile friendly and am using the google site: https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/mobile-friendly/. Instead of going to the site and typing in each address I want to write a script to automate it.

An example to check Amazon for example would be:

```
wget https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/mobile-friendly/?url=amazon.com
```

I have tried changing the user agent string and accepting cookies as well but it keeps just loading the main page.

Comment: The Google site uses Javascript. `wget` doesn't run scripts.

Answer (score 0):

`wget` will download the page as is. This means JS code won't be executed.

Maybe could help:

- [wget + JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5901661/wget-javascript)
- [Command line browser with js
  support](https://superuser.com/questions/448514/command-line-browser-with-js-support)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for the help. I was able to figure a way out. One way is to use phantomjs. You create a script like below that I named save.js:

```
var system = require('system');
var page = require('webpage').create();

page.open(system.args[1], function()
{
    console.log(page.content);
    phantom.exit();
});
```

Then I run the code as follows:

phantomjs save.js http://www.google.com > output.html

Another way is to use selenium with python. Here is a code snippet from python that will print the html.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.set_window_size(1024,768)
driver.get('www.google.com')
print driver.page_source
driver.quit()
```