# Browse url, possibly with dynamic content, from command line and save html for DOM

Tags: javascript, html, dom, browser, command-line

I basically need a dynamic version of wget. wget is great for static pages, but when a page runs javascript to load and display stuff, wget can't be used to obtain the html you "see".

So what's the simplest way from the command line (assume Mac or Unix) to launch a browser (e.g. Firefox or Chrome), load a url in that browser, wait a few seconds for any javascript to run which may load dynamic content, then finally save html associated with the current DOM to a file?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5901661/wget-javascript

Comment: tampermonkey is my favorite for scraping; much easier to tweak and debug than pretend browsers